# a way to script automatically to start and stop the sql database in gcp

Tags: google-cloud-sql

i want to run a job in cloud scheduler in gcp to start and stop the sql database in weekdays at working hours.

I have tried by triggering cloud function and using pubsub but i am not getting proper way to do it.

Comment: provide your code, what you tried, the error you got etc. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Cloud SQL Admin API to start or stop and instance. Depending on your language, there are clients available to help you do this. [This page contains examples using curl](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/start-stop-restart-instance).

Once you've created two Cloud Functions (one to start, and one to stop), you can configure the Cloud Scheduler to send a pub/sub trigger to your function. Check out [this tutorial which walks you through the process](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/tut-pub-sub).

Comment: Hi, 

Can u please provide me the code and procedure as i am new to this so i need ur help.

Thank youi

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this you can use a [Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-python) to make a call to the [Cloud SQL Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/v1beta4/) to start and stop your Cloud SQL instance (you will need 2 Cloud functions). You can see my code on how to use a Cloud Function to [start a Cloud SQL instance](https://github.com/chris32g/Google-Cloud-Support/blob/master/Cloud%20Functions/turn_on_cloudSQL_instance) and [stop a Cloud SQL instance](https://github.com/chris32g/Google-Cloud-Support/blob/master/Cloud%20Functions/turn_off_CloudSQL_instance)

After creating your Cloud Function you can [configure the Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/quickstart) to trigger the http address of each Cloud function