# Change sql instances in Google Cloud

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Is there a script to start/stop MySql instances in Google Cloud every four hours? I can't find it, only console or gcloud and it is not automaticly made, so it is no good.

Comment: To clarify, there's nothing in Cloud SQL for this, no...but as Jasper answered, you could write a quick script to do it and use Cloud Scheduler to fire it off every 4 hours.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [a way to script automatically to start and stop the sql database in gcp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57264307/a-way-to-script-automatically-to-start-and-stop-the-sql-database-in-gcp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [cloud scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler) for this. You can set this as frequency: `0 */4 * * *` (do something every 4 hours). As target you can send a HTTP request to the Google Cloud REST API and patch the [activation policy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/start-stop-restart-instance#rest), or you can trigger a cloud function to first check the status of the SQL instance and based on that decide to start or stop it.